How to make sure a payment is actually received and will not bounce, using Paypal, Stripe or online banking respectively?
I recently saw some social media posts about a scam going around targeting artists, where the scammer would pretend to commission art, overpay the artist, then ask for the overpaid amount to be refunded. After the victim does so, the original payment would “bounce”, and the victim is now out of pocket.
My question is, how do you know if money received (on e.g. Paypal, Stripe, online banking etc.) is actually received, and will not “bounce”? My understanding is that this type of balance is different from say, if the payment is actually complete and the sender later disputes it, which is another story. It sounds like in this type of scam the money isn’t actually there to begin with. Is there any indication we can find that suggests that this is shaky money?
In addition, I feel as if people who are not professionals in the financial field, such as myself, rarely think of the underlying things beneath the balance that appears to be in our accounts. I would appreciate if someone could explain some of the fundamentals not just in regards to this type of scams, but also when sending and receiving money in general, or point me to some further reads. Thank you so much!

You can not, it is impossible.  Checks can be revoked.  Anything, whatsoever can be revoked.  Note that cash payments can be revoked, by the cops or in court.  This is a basic of how the financial world works.

Stripe supports partial refunds to the original payment method; you could safely do that.

"It sounds like in this type of scam the money isn’t actually there to begin with." - whether the money is "actually there" is inconsequential. Would you really feel better if, instead of stolen electronic funds, you received a stolen physical television, and then the police physically showed up at your house a month later to confiscate it?

What I seem to be missing in all these scams: they all seem to rely on the victim getting money in a reversible way, paying some of it back in an irreversible way, then the original payment gets reversed. OK. But then: all answers seem to say that "no payment is irreversible", so why doesn't the victim just reverse their "repayment" after the original payment was reversed by a scammer? ...

... If there are both reversible and irreversible modes, couldn't the victim insist on (a) either receiving the money "irreversibly" from the counterparty/potential scammer in the first place, or (b) "repaying" in a reversible mode, and then reversing this "repayment" after the first payment was reversed by a scammer? Wouldn't either of these be possible counters to this particular scam?

Rule of thumb is that anything that involves an overpayment and reimbursement by some other means is a scam. In fact, most thing that involve you committing to paying the other party, or a third party, when you're the one doing the work or owning the asset are scams. For example, the creeps who will pretend to be interested in a car for sale, string you along and then ask for a carfax-like (but not carfax, obviously) "report" before they buy.

@StephanKolassa The scammer's payment has grounds to be reversed -- it wasn't authorized by the person whose funds were transferred. The victim has no grounds to reverse the payment -- they did authorize the transfer and they were the owner of the funds. The payment is made to another scam victim who was tricked into making an irreversible payment like gift cards or crypto.

Related: Counterfeit checks were created for my account. How does this type of fraud work?

You can't. That's what these scams hinge on. The whole point is that transactions that are fraudulent can be reversed. The way these scams are set up is that the victim sends their money willingly, while the money they received comes from sources obtained through fraud and which end up being reversed. As such, they're used to launder scammers' money, and are the one left holding the bag as the last point of trace of the fraudulent transaction.

Some more points from the comments:
Funds on hold - deposited funds may be held unavailable for use for a short period of time. But them becoming available doesn't mean the transaction will never be reversed. The holds are usually short (up to a week), and usually not for the full amount. The holds are based on the bank's trust of the victim and whether they believe the victim will do something like that. Moreover, holds are usually partial (e.g.: the first $200 are available immediately, the rest is on hold).
How long after the deposit can it be reversed - months. In the US (and many other places) customers are given 60 days after statement to report irregularities. I.e.: the original owner may report that the check was stolen or the withdrawal was unauthorized up to 3 months later. The original bank then investigates, victim's bank investigates, and it will take some more time for the decision to reverse to happen. By that time the scammers are long gone. Victim, as I said, transferred the money on their own and willingly, and has no recourse.

That would be a depressing answer. So are you telling me the bank is not capable of telling when a payment is fully received? That sounds bizarre. The bank surely knows if, when and how a transaction can be reversed. Otherwise you can NEVER be sure of any cent in your account. Would a payment that has been received 3 years ago still be reversible?

This is a very good question. I honestly see so many scams like this it doesn't make sense to me. Is this a thing with US banks only? Because in Australia, once money hits your bank account it's yours. The only way I know of to "reverse" the transaction (and this is very, very rare) is if the other party disputes the payment, but that is a long, tedious process for them and would absolutely expose any scammer, so it's not done.

I would have thought waiting 5 working days before issuing refunds would go some way towards helping here without being too unreasonable for bona fide customers. How long do these transactions usually take to bounce?

@Hilmar the bank doesn't know that the money was stolen because the theft might not have been even discovered by the time you received the transfer. Once the bank learns that - the money gets returned immediately. There's no situation we're the bank knows the transfer is going to be reversed but let's you use the money.

@user3490 customers have 60 days after statement to report irregularities, so it could literally be multiple months.

@user3490 Because people don't necessarily keep a close eye on their accounts. Somebody might be a victim of forgery or hacking and not be aware of it for some time. It may be weeks or months before they finally catch on. With forged checks, the banks will do the electronic part of the money transfer after a brief holding period, but this is a courtesy to their customer. The physical check may have to get back to the bank and get caught in a quality control check before the fraud is detected. That can take weeks or months.

@Hilmar "So are you telling me the bank is not capable of telling when a payment is fully received? " Banks are not oracles, and much of this is beyond their control. For example, fraudulent payments made to hide assets in bankruptcy can be clawed back by the court up to a year later. Do you really expect the bank to be able to warn you "Hey, this person is going to declare bankruptcy in a month. Don't accept their payment!".  In the end it's up to the customer to decide whether a payment poses a fraud risk or not.

@Arj Generally, the money doesn't come from the scammer, but from some other victim. They (or their bank) might want the money back, and it won't expose the scammer.

@PaŭloEbermann That still doesn't explain the root cause. Why does this seem to always happen in the US and never in Australia? What magic wand do we wave in Oz to prevent this from happening, and why can't it be applied in the US?

"the original owner may report that the check was stolen or the withdrawal was unauthorized up to 3 months later" But what about an ordinary bank transfer that is initiated by the one paying? In Germany, these are quite common and very hard to revoke.

@Stefan the scam hinges on laundering fraudulent transfers. What's the point for the scammer to initiate a transfer from their own account?

I don't know, but the OP's question was "how do you know if money received is actually received, and will not “bounce”?" Wouldn't a valid answer be "if it was received by an ordinary bank transfer"?

@Stefan no, because if it was transferred through fraud it could still be reversed. Wire transfers are more secure in that regard, even those could be reversed in extreme situations.

What strikes me as odd is the idea that the victim "transferred the money on their own and willingly, and has no recourse". What if the victim was blackmailed or signed a check at gunpoint? Would that also be "willingly"? In all cases, the victim is obviously victim of a fraud, a crime, and it seems entirely counter-intuitive and unjust hat they cannot reverse that transaction the same way as the victim of, say, check theft can revoke the original, also fraudulent transaction.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica they can through legal action. Anyone can tell a story that they've been scammed to back out of a payment, it's not up to the banks to be arbiters.

@littleadv Yeah, I understand that, to a degree. On the other hand, it's the victim executing both the transaction and the revocation; the laws or rules could still allow (and often do) a grace period for revoking one's own money. Yes, that would introduce a period of insecurity, but that exists anyway, especially with checks. The bank, in principle, does not need to be the arbiter of anything: They simply execute the customer's wishes over their money, which is the entire raison d'être of a bank. Civil liabilities for non-payment etc. would be solely the customer's.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica there usually is a period to cancel a transaction, but once the money left - it left. It wasn't stolen, nothing was forged, the victim gave an instruction. Allowing people to claw back money from other people's accounts will lead to chaos.

@littleadv Re "chaos": As has been mentioned, various other forms of (willing, voluntary ;-) ) payment do have such grace periods. Another case is that in Germany, where automatic withdrawal is very common, the payer has quite long revocation rights for them. That's of course necessary because they don't initiate each specific payment; but they did give the general authorization, and the payee cannot be sure that the money stays on their account for several weeks.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica right, but that's a withdrawal, not transfer. Sure, I can give a general authorization five years ago and forget about it. In this case we're talking not about a general, but about a very specific instruction. I understand your point, but there's a line in the sand, and that's where it is.

The most essential point is to never send money to, or for, or to enable, someone who is supposed to be paying you. Legitimate finance never works that way.
There are two basic attack modes here. One is that checks and electronic transfers can bounce for lack of funds, or be canceled, or be made from a stolen account, and it can take a significant amount of time for to resolve that, during which your bank will display the funds as present but on hold.  If a scammer can convince you to send money during this verification, and then cancel the deposit or have it fail, they have just stolen your money. Exactly how long it takes for a transaction to clear and become final depends in part on the kind of transaction and your own bank' rules, so you should talk to them about when you can count on a deposit being final, or as close to final as it's going to be -- assuming it was legal in the first place; see the next point.
The second attack vector is that they may be trying to use you to launder illegal funds. In this scenario, the deposit is real, but is made from a criminal's account. If they can get you to send that money somewhere else, they now have money that looks legitimate, and you have participated in a crime. Illegal payments can also be canceled, and even if they aren't, you can be prosecuted.
The third attack vector, of course, is identity theft.
If you refuse to send money or other valuables, and do not give them more information than us legitimately needed to pay you (see many web articles on identity theft), then the worst that can happen is that the money you receive is fairy gold and vanishes when sunlight hits it. They can get you to waste time, and postage, but if you are careful you can limit it to that.
If you are selling physical goods, there is a risk of those being stolen, but that is part of doing business by mail order; again there are articles on the web describing what you can do to protect yourself, and what to do if a payment bounces. But the majority of scammers want your money, not your product.
And finally, I will refer you to the many existing web articles on how to recognize a scam, the kinds of scams that are common (most are variance on a few simple themes), what information you should and shouldn't be willing to give people, and how to validate a business's identity. Remember that if it sounds too good to be true, it probably isn't true, and that if they're trying to rush you, it is probably because they don't want you to think about what they're asking you to do. And remember that on the internet, in mail, or even in person, you can never be certain that anybody is who they claim to be.

That's all fine and well but doesn't actually answer the question: "How do you know when a payment has fully  and the money is truly yours", which IMO is aa very good question.

Hi thanks for the answer. I think the key factor here is as you said the money is “on hold”. Is “on hold” the standard term across all the platforms I mentioned, which as I assume will be attached to the payment as some sort of label that us regular users can see?

No, the money won't be on hold. That's the whole point.

@HullBreaker banks in the US will typically make funds from a deposit available a few days after the deposit date. This is not a guarantee that the deposit is cleared and valid! It is done as a "courtesy" to the customer. The customer, not the bank, is finally on the hook for having accepted a fraudulent payment. Talk to any merchant about the problems they have with bad checks. Be vigilant about who you do business with, and be aware of red flags that are associated with fraud (like being asked to send back money from deliberate overpayments, or requests to transfer funds to a 3rd party).

@Hilmar: You can't, if we include risks like the payment having been made using stolen credentials for a bank account and the legitimate account holder demanding it be returned. All you can do is minimize your risks. That starts with being sure who your customer is.

@HullBreaker The key point to take away is that there is no sure way of knowing it. If there was, those scams wouldn't exist. These scams being alive and kicking shows, or even more, proves that there's no obvious solution to rely on other than you learning what to look out for and not falling for it in the first place.

@Hilmar The money is fully and truly yours as soon as you can demonstrate that you are legally entitled to it. Because in that case, no matter what happens to the payment, you can still sue the person who was legally obligated to pay you that money. Otherwise, no matter what happens the person who sent you the money can sue you to get it back and you won't be able to show that you're entitled to it, so they will likely win since they can prove they were entitled to it previously.

@DavidSchwartz: Of course the question then becomes whether this transaction is worth that effort.

Answering the title question:
This depends on a payment method and a bank. Paypal can reverse charges even months after you receive it. Credit card payments can again be reversed even months after.
Banks - it depends on how it was received. Wire Transfers can't be easily reversed (they still can in rare cases). Cheques can bounce up to two months after.
Answering how to avoid the scam:
Never, ever send money forward. Always use the refund option on the payment method.

Really, the question is "when am I entitled to keep money that I am not entitled to keep". And then it's clear that the answer is "never".

@Dawid Shwartz - Well not really. Unfortunately evil clients exist that will try to reverse payments for services rendered. Had this happen to me decades ago when I was freelancing, and I understand it's still a problem even now. That's one of the reasons why so many people in USA now prefer cashapp over paypal.

In addition to the other answers: even if the method by which you receive the money is itself irreversible, it does not mean that a judge cannot decide to force you to pay the money back, if it is deemed that the transaction was illegal (e.g. stolen identity).
The only limit would be those of the statute of limitations, but those times are measured in years (I would point to 5 years in my country).
